# Combine the name of a fictional species and a way to cook eggs to find the answer

Tags: word

Take the 3-letter name of an intelligent, non-human species from a major fictional book series. (Make sure the species name is in singular form, "cat" instead of "cat**s**").

Next, name a 5-letter way that refers to the way you might cook your eggs: _____ eggs.

Now, take the first 3 letters of the way you cook your eggs, drop them in front of the 3-letter species name, and replace the last letter of the species name with the last letter of the way you cook your eggs. Now, you'll get the relationship of this species to the main protagonist in this fictional series. What is this relationship?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is

> Friend
>  Species: ENT Eggs: FRIED
>  Following the instructions we get:
>  FRIENT
>  FRIEND

Comment: nice! I did not expect anyone to get the answer that quickly!

Comment: Haha, and I'm only a poor to mediocre puzzler. Wait until you see what some of our experts can do to the most hideously complex of puzzles.

Comment: @fi12 this was a good first puzzle, but you'll have to do much better to challenge the guys here. You see, this one was quite easy to crack because 'fried' was pretty much the only 5-letter method I could think of, so even without any clue to the 3-letter word you can already get FRIxxD. Guessing the answer gives you EN and then it's really simple to find a matching fictional species even if you don't know it.